# Xamarin Forms - Bind Label to a Command

Tags: xamarin.forms, command, label

Is there a way to bind a Label to a command so when certain event (**not a touch event**) has occurred, the command will fire?
Has anyone done something like this?

Comment: a Label is not really an interactive UI element.  What kind of event are you talking about?

Comment: what event has to occurred?

Comment: Please check the links below, maybe can help you.
https://www.davidbritch.com/2018/10/creating-hyperlink-in-xamarinforms.html
https://www.davidbritch.com/2018/10/creating-hyperlink-in-xamarinforms-ii.html

Comment: Not sure, could be Focused or TextChanged since I will scan into it.  I currently use an invisible Entry to scan into it but the problem with that is that it shows keyboard and I dont want keyboard to show at all.  So, I thought to use Label instead

Answer (score 0):

When you are using MVVM, we can able to fire an event in the code behind..

See the below sample:

In the Xaml code behind, override OnBindingContextChanged() method and register property changed event in it. So whenever, the value changes in the bindable property, this event will be fired. You can check the property name inside this event and do your logic.

view model declaration,

```
private MyApplicationsViewModel bindingv;
```

BindingContext override,

```
protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
            base.OnBindingContextChanged();
            bindingv = (this.BindingContext as MyApplicationsViewModel);
            if (bindingv != null)
            {
                bindingv.PropertyChanged += Bindingv_PropertyChanged;
            }
    }
```

PropertyChanged event method should be below, You can add your logic by checking the property that you have assigned before,

```
 async void Bindingv_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(bindingv.FirstName)) // your property name which is used in the label binding
        {
        }
    }
```